# Apache memory allocation error message

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat

I'm trying to set up a medium sized Drupal 7 website on my miniserver but I keep getting a 500 error message. This is what I found in Apache's error log:

```
[Wed Sep 12 15:02:04 2012] [notice] SSL FIPS mode disabled
[Wed Sep 12 15:02:04 2012] [warn] No JkShmFile defined in httpd.conf. Using default /usr/local/apache/logs/jk-runtime-status
[Wed Sep 12 15:02:04 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 mod_jk/1.2.35 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Sep 12 15:02:07 2012] [error] [client 89.16.136.28] /usr/bin/php: error while loading shared libraries: libkrb5support.so.0: failed to map segment from shared object: Cannot allocate memory
[Wed Sep 12 15:02:07 2012] [error] [client 89.16.136.28] Premature end of script headers: index.php
[Wed Sep 12 15:02:07 2012] [error] [client 89.16.136.28] /usr/bin/php: error while loading shared libraries: libkrb5support.so.0: failed to map segment from shared object: Cannot allocate memory
[Wed Sep 12 15:02:07 2012] [error] [client 89.16.136.28] Premature end of script headers: index.php
[Wed Sep 12 15:02:07 2012] [error] [client 89.16.136.28] File does not exist: /home/brighton/public_html/favicon.ico
[Wed Sep 12 15:02:07 2012] [error] [client 89.16.136.28] /usr/bin/php: error while loading shared libraries: libkrb5support.so.0: failed to map segment from shared object: Cannot allocate memory
[Wed Sep 12 15:02:07 2012] [error] [client 89.16.136.28] Premature end of script headers: index.php
```

I contacted support and they just told me I should just upgrade my package (right not I have a 512Mb account), but I am not sure if I'm buying it... even if I'm trying to access a file which only contains phpinfo(); I still get the 500.

Any help would be much appreciated, and if there's need of any other information please let me know and I'll update the question. I compiled apache with tomcat because I intend to use Solr... not sure if this is relevant or not.

Comment: Please show us your `top`?

Comment: @quanta here's the screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/7GE0V.png

Comment: Can you also add the output from `free -m`? It looks like you've just run out of memory and have no VM so once the RAM is used up things that need memory just won't work anymore.

Comment: @uesp here's that output: http://i.imgur.com/73HYQ.png

Comment: Its probably not due to low memory then as you have plenty of memory in the "cache" which could be used for applications.

Comment: any possible solutions for something like this?

Comment: Stop using OpenVZ.

Answer (score 0):

Give some memory limitation in JAVA_OPTS, like the parameter "-Xmx256m". I advise you this solution but in some JDK seems to don't work properly.